# VBScript output shell.run to log file

Tags: vbscript

I know there are a few answers to this already but I am unsure why the answers are not working. I will list what I have done.

Basically I want to log information from a `shell.Run` command into a log file.

What I have

```vb
Dim WshShell
Dim WshProcEnv

Set WshShell =  CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run """C:\Program Files\Folder\batchFile.bat""", 1, TRUE
```

Which successfully runs the batch file.

So looking at answers like [this one](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/207a390b-bc56-4a43-b54f-d32dd170d9f0/piping-to-a-log-file-in-vbscript?forum=ITCG) I have tried the following:

```vb
WshShell.Run "cmd /c C:\Program Files\Folder\batchFile.bat > C:\Program Files\Folder\log.txt", 1, TRUE

WshShell.Run "cmd /c ""C:\Program Files\Folder\batchFile.bat > C:\Program Files\Folder\log.txt""", 1, TRUE

WshShell.Run """cmd.exe /c ""C:\Program Files\Folder\batchFile.bat > C:\Program Files\Folder\log.txt""", 1, TRUE
```

I believe it's something small hence why I've asked a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put quotes around each individual path that contain spaces, not the whole commandline.

```vb
WshShell.Run "cmd /c ""C:\Program Files\Folder\batchFile.bat"" > ""C:\Program Files\Folder\log.txt""", 1, True
```

Usually the best way of handling stuff like this is to put your paths in variables and do the quoting with a user-defined quoting function:

```vb
Function qq(str)
  qq = """" & str & """"
End Function

batchfile = "C:\Program Files\Folder\batchFile.bat"
logfile   = "C:\Program Files\Folder\log.txt"

WshShell.Run "cmd /c " & qq(batchfile) & " > " & qq(logfile), 1, True
```

That greatly helps with keeping your statements readable.